# How to merge two different implode variable into one array?

Tags: php, arrays

Below is my code:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$qty = $_GET['qty'];
$product_id=$_GET['product_id'];
```

This is how I receive in the browser

```
http://example.com/shopping_cart.php?id=17,18&qty=4,5&product_id=3

$_SESSION['test'][]= array('product_id'=>$product_id,array('id'=>$id,'qty'=>$qty));

//print_r($_SESSION['test']);
foreach($_SESSION['test'] as $item=>$value)
{
    echo "Main Array ID=". $item;
    echo "<br/>";
    foreach($value as $v=>$v1)
    {
        if(is_array($v1))
        {
        echo "Sub Array ID=". $v;
        echo "<br/>";
        echo "size id=". $v1['id'];
        echo "<br/>";
        echo "Quantity=". $v1['qty'];
        echo "<br/>";
        }
    }
 }
```

Output:

```
Main Array ID=0
Sub Array ID=0
size id=12,13
Quantity=1,2
Main Array ID=1
Sub Array  ID=0
size id=17,18
Quantity=4,5
```

Since `size_id` and `quantity` are in implode form, I mean they have a comma ',' in between the value. I need to explode them and use `foreach` to display one by one.

I mean something like this:

```
$size_id1=explode(',',$v1['qty']);
foreach($size_id1 as $size_id2)
{
    echo $size_id2;
}

$qty1=explode(',',$v1['qty']);
foreach($qty1 as $qty2)
{
    echo $qty2;
}
```

What I need is, I want to display matching `size_id` and `qty`. For example, instead of displaying:

```
size_id 1
size_id 2

Qty 1
Qty 2
```

It should display:

```
Size_id 1 Qty 1
Size_id 2 Qty 2
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Use a normal `for` with $i=0;$i<count($i);$i++ and get the same value in the same position $i `$ids[$i]; $qty[$i]......`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ids = $_GET['id']
$qtys = $_GET['qty']
$product_id = $_GET['product_id'];

$tmp_result = array();
$ids = explode(',',$ids );
$i = 0;
foreach($ids as $id)
{          
      $tmp_result[$i]['id'] =  $id;
      $i++;
}

$i = 0;
$qtys =explode(',',$qtys );
foreach($qtys as $qty)
{          
      $tmp_result[$i]['qty'] =  $qty;
      $i++;
}    

$_SESSION['tmp_results'][$product_id] = $tmp_result;
```

Comment: Thanks alot ,it worked. I have one concern. I changed $tmp_result into $_SESSION['tmp_result'].Coz I want each record to be added into the shopping cart. But it doesn't seem to work. It still displays only the latest products. Can help in this pls? Thanks.

Comment: What this line used for? $result = array('product_key' => $product_id,$_SESSION['tmp_result']);

Comment: therfore you have the product id. Use $_SESSION['tmp_results'][$product_id] to save it.
The other line you can ignore! I'll update my code for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
$temp_arr = array();
$id_str = '17,18';
$qty_str = '4,5';
foreach(array_combine(explode(',', $id_str), explode(',', $qty_str)) as $k => $v) {
    $temp_arr[]['id'] = $k;
    $temp_arr[]['qty'] = $v;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

diffrence betwen 2 implode fetch from database

```
<?php  
 $select_tbl=mysql_query("select * from user_reg where uid='".           $_SESSION['user1']."'");
while($fetch=mysql_fetch_object($select_tbl))
{
$r=$fetch->specialised;

$i=explode(",",$r);
$length = count($i);
for ($x=0; $x<$length; $x++)
{     
 echo $i[$x]; }
}?><tbody>
  <?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("freelancer");
$query=mysql_query("select * from post_proj where status = 1 and payment =  '' ") or die(mysql_error());
$j = 1;
while($result=mysql_fetch_array($query))
{                   
if($result['uid'] == "")
{$d2 = $result['proj_skill'];
$pantry_food1 = explode(",",$d2);
$count_total1 = count($pantry_food1);
for ($counter=0; $counter<$count_total1; $counter++){
$line1 = each ($pantry_food1);
// echo $pantry_food1[$counter];
} $rrt = array_intersect($i,$pantry_food1);
```

Comment: what is this? this code is not even relevant to OP code and where is the difference?